# How to add self to ManyToManyField by default?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-signals

Is it possible to add `self` - I mean the current object it's `ManyToManyField`?

```
class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    country = models.ForeignKey('Country')
    close_cities = models.ManyToManyField('City',blank=True, related_name='close_cities_set')
```

If I create let's say `x = City.objects.create(...)`, I want the `x` to be a part of `close_cities` by default.

I can't find anything related to this problem. I tried to overwrite `create()` method but it did not worked.

After trying, I decided to create a signal which adds the city after creating an instance. Unfortunately this does not work but I can't figure out why. The signal is being called, the condition `if created` is `True` (checked).

```
@receiver(post_save,sender=myapp_models.City)
def add_self_into_many_to_many_field(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        instance.close_cities.add(instance)
        instance.save()
```

Do you know where is the problem?

Comment: If I understand you, you want to add City `x` to itself as a `close_city`?

Comment: Yes. x is the city. And I want x to be a part of x.close_cities

Comment: IF you want a table to have a many to many relationship with itself, you __probably__ have the wrong design.

Comment: What if you add a `property` called `close_cities` and you return what you have in your field plus the object itself?

Comment: have you tried `close_cities = models.ManyToManyField("self")`?

Comment: @fodma1 This is an option, I was considering it and if the signal won't work, this is the way.

Comment: @Compadre I don't think that this will help. It's the same as my.

Comment: @e4c5 This seems to be simple. In admin, I can put self into the manytomany so I suppose it should be possible to do it using signal.

Answer (score 0):

In this case `pre_save` signal will be better solution.

In Your solution `city.save` calls `add_self_into_many_to_many_field`. `instance.save` calls `add_self_into_many_to_many_field`. and so on...

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=myapp_models.City)
def add_self_into_many_to_many_field(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if instance.pk is None:
        instance.close_cities.add(instance)
```

Comment: That's why the "created" condition is there. The code is executed only if the object has been created, not saved. Moreover, pre_save doesn't contains instance because it hasn't been saved yet in my opinion. If I change it to pre_save - the error is being raised: add_self_into_many_to_many_field() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)

Comment: `pre_save` accept three parameters: `instance`, `raw` and `using`.

Comment: So it hasn't "created" parameter, so I can't do that just once. I think that post_save should be better If I'm right that it's executed just once. Don't you think? I tried your solution but this error is raised: Exception Value: 
"<City: Czech Republic, Kosice>" needs to have a value for field "from_city" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.